# Bundling my javascript will raise the folloiwng exception "Expected identifier: ("

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I am working on Asp.Net MVC Core web project, where i have those scripts inside my `_layout` view, and the scripts are working well:-

```
        <script src="~/js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/ajax-form.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/scrollIt.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/nice-select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/contact.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/mail-script.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/mvc-grid/mvc-grid.js"></script>
```

But to improve the response time of my application, i bundle the above javascript, using the following inside my `bundleconfig.json`:-

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site5.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site5.css", 
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/mainbundle.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/mainbundle.js",
      "wwwroot/js/vendor/modernizr-3.5.0.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/popper.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/bootstrap.min.js", 
      "wwwroot/js/owl.carousel.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/ajax-form.js",
      "wwwroot/js/waypoints.min.js",   
      "wwwroot/js/jquery.counterup.min.js",  
      "wwwroot/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/scrollIt.js",
      "wwwroot/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/wow.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/nice-select.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
      "wwwroot/js/plugins.js"
      "wwwroot/js/slick.min.js",    
      "wwwroot/js/contact.js",

      "wwwroot/js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js",

      "wwwroot/js/jquery.form.js",

      "wwwroot/js/jquery.validate.min.js",

      "wwwroot/js/mail-script.js",

      "wwwroot/js/main.js",

      "wwwroot/js/mvc-grid/mvc-grid.js"

    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

but when i run the project using Visual Studio i got this exception on the bundle file:-`"Expected identifier: ("` as follow:-
[image]

Comment: I think it means you have typo in you mainbundle.min.js file

Comment: @Ludolfyn the `mainbundle.min.js ` is empty